# Intellisense for every variable (object) in C# show GetHashCode(), ToString(), Equals(), GetType()

Tags: c#, methods, intellisense

In my programming life in C#, whenever I create some variable (or object) in C# when I write .(dot) Intellisense for this variable (object) show me standard 4 methods.

For example I create empty class `SomeClass`

```
public class SomeClass
{

}
```

When I create object of this class, and call some methods, even if this class is empty intellisense show me this 4 methods.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
       +---------------+
    sc.|Equals         |
       |GetHashCode    |
       |GetType        |
       |ToString       |
       +---------------+
}
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All classes inherit from `System.Object` - which contains those methods.

Answer (score 3):

Every class implicitly inherit from the [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) class, from the `System.Object` namespace. Basically, it's the root of the type hierarchy.

Also, besides those 4 methods you pointed out, every object also inherit the `Finalize` method from `Object`.

Since your class inherits from Object, that statement would be valid :

```
object sc = new SomeClass();
```